# firefox: from which sites has the autofill data been recorded

Tags: firefox, autocomplete

Recently, I discovered a very important error in the autocomplete data in firefox. Once I was required to enter the date I obtained my MSc on some website. I did that and proceeded. A month or two later I was asked about the date again on a different website apparently using the same template as the first website. The autocomplete information popped up, and, voilá, I noticed that I had typed in a wrong date back then. I would like to repair my typo on the first website, but, alas, I remember nothing about the first website: neither the organization nor the URL nor the title... **Is there an easy way to recover the URL of the website from which autocomplete data was recorded?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, autocomplete has no log that would allow you to show where it was used.

Your best bet would be to search your Firefox history - assuming you have not cleared your data.

To access your history click on the History menu -> display all and search for anything relevant to the site you have been on.

Comment: No problem, please flag the question as answered...

Comment: done ;-) per your recommendation